# Sobre Crystal Reports, Visual Basic 2010 e MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

Possuo um projeto de clínica odontológica, o qual possui um formulário de ficha de tratamento. Tal formulário possui 160 botões que representam os 32 dentes de um paciente
(cada dente é representado por um conjunto de 5 botões);

Os botões podem ter 5 status diferentes (o que varia é sua cor de fundo), ou também pode não ter sido marcado.

[image: Imagem do Formulário]

O status de cada dente é armazenado em um banco de dados Mysql que possui 32 campos (1 para cada dente);

a forma mais eficaz que encontrei para armazená-los foi a seguinte. Como cada dente é um conjunto de 5 botões, cada campo receberá uma String do seguinte formato: "0;1;5;3;2" por exemplo. Cada número representa um status diferente de cada um dos 5 botões.

É aí que vem a questão:
Como faria para reproduzir tais dentes e seus diferentes estados em um relatório (Crystal Reports)?

Espero que possam me ajudar.
Agradeço desde já...

Comment: Vamos lá, primeiro depende o que se representar, é uma ficha dentária, visual , próxima de uma dentistas usam ? É um relatório operacional ?

Comment: O relatório será uma espécie de orçamento, e deverá conter dados como código da ficha, início e fim de tratamento, etc (até aí sei como funciona). Meu maior problema é ter que representar, no relatório, os dentes para que fiquem representados de forma parecida à da imagem do post.

Comment: "0;1;5;3;2" diz como formatar o "dente" suponho, uma solução simples que vejo seria criar 5 fórmulas para cada dente e montar a imagem , o resto é replicar 31 vezes, mas, existe no Sistema a imagem pronta ? Ela poderia ser carregada no CR.

Comment: Não existe imagem pronta! o que quero saber é se, na verdade, exite uma forma de utilizar os controles existentes no CR (como um painel ou algo semelhante, por exemplo) e preenchê-los de formas diferentes (de acordo com os números que representam o dente),

Comment: Talvez um gráfico, mas eu faria algo simples 5 letrinhas representando o dente, como o dado do BD vira informação visual ?

Comment: o dado do bd é carregado em botões como na imagem do post. como cada dente é representado por 5 botões, eu faço uma busca no banco e resultará em uma string, por exemplo "0;1;5;3;2". Depois eu quebro a string separando os números e com um "simples" if preencho os botões com as cores correspondentes.

Comment: Sim, mas como a imagem é montada?

Comment: não existe imagem.. esse é o ponto. objetivo é trazer para o relatório algo semelhante aos botões que representam o dente

Comment: Ok, mas como a cruzinha é preenchida ? Vermelho, azul, X ...

Comment: é preenchida utilizando um select que retornará uma string e com alguns IFs. a string será, por exemplo "5;0;1;2;3". O número 1 representa a cor vermelha, 2 representa a cinza, 3 a azul, 4 o x, e 5 a barra. Se for 0 o o botão não será preenchido. A posição desses números pode variar é claro e cada posição representa um botão da cruzinha. "cima;direita;baixo;esquerda;centro".

Comment: Entendi, vou pensar uma solução em CR.

Comment: Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução simples que vejo é criar 5 Fórmulas para cada Dente e formatar a regra, o resto é um feio "copiar e colar"

```
   f1
f2 f3 f4
   f5
```

No Editar Formula, algo como

```
If {Comando.CAMPO} = "1" THEN
  "x"
ELSE
  " "
```

Não é a mais "limpa" das soluções , mas a que mais se aproxima do Form original.

---

A outra solução seria usar um "OLE object dynamic", é vincular a Regra à um bitmap já existente.

Da documentação do Crystal Reports Versão 11

Making a static OLE object dynamic
A dynamic static OLE object is a picture or metafile that you access in Crystal Reports by use of a file path or URL. Typically, you use this option when you have the path to your pictures or metafiles stored as a string field in a database (that is, you do not have the actual objects stored in the database). You can also use this option when you have pictures or metafiles stored on a network share, and you know these objects change occasionally. 
The functionality of these dynamic static OLE objects (or dynamic graphics) is created in Crystal Reports through the use of a conditional formatting formula that allows you to link to static OLE objects by reference. 
Note: 
This feature is activated when you refresh your report data; therefore, you may not notice a change in the static OLE object until you click the Refresh button in Crystal Reports. 
When you schedule a report that contains a dynamic static OLE object in SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise, the instances that are created contain the version of the static OLE object as it existed in your Crystal report when you scheduled it. SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise does not update the object dynamically for each instance. 
Reports that use an absolute or a relative path for a dynamic static OLE object are not supported in an SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise environment for this release. If you plan to publish reports that contain dynamic static OLE objects to SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise, it is recommend that you use URL links for your OLE objects. 
In this section:
To make a static OLE object dynamic

To make a static OLE object dynamic
Right-click the static OLE object that you inserted, and choose Format Graphic from the shortcut menu.

Note: You begin the process of making a static OLE object dynamic by inserting the object into your report as usual. This object becomes the default object. If Crystal Reports cannot find the dynamic reference to the object, it uses the default object instead. 
In the Format Editor, click the Picture tab, and then click the Conditional Formula button adjacent to the Graphic Location label. 
In the Formula Workshop, create the path to your static OLE object. 
For example, if your path is stored in a database field, add that field to the formula. 
Click Save and close to return to the Format Editor. 
Click OK to return to your report. 
Click Refresh to update the reference link to your static OLE object.

--
Mas não testei isto.

Comment: Desculpe pela demora em responder.. o que fiz foi adotar a primeira solução.. foi um pouco demorado e pouco prático mas resolveu e o resultado agradou.. Muito Obrigado!!

Comment: Como 32 dentes não deve mudar tão cedo ...